# python number formatting in list values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the list

```
 value = {'a': [['1312.98680732', 14.28625384], 
                ['1312.98680735', 20.303], 
                ['1312.98680736', 9.78438636]], 
          'b': [['1307.00000001', 0.02968967], 
                ['1307.00000000', 1.948], 
                ['1306.53301802', 0.02]], 
          'c': 0, 
          'd': 226843654}
```

I am able to extract and get

```
a = [['1312.98680732', 14.28625384], 
     ['1312.98680735', 20.303], 
     ['1312.98680736', 9.78438636]]
```

However I need to convert the quoted values from string to float.

Desired output:

```
a = [[1312.98680732, 14.28625384], 
     [1312.98680735, 20.303], 
     [1312.98680736, 9.78438636]]
```

I tried `list(map(float, a)` but it is working only if I have one value.

Comment: You applied `float` to the elements of `a`, which are 2-item lists.  You need to apply it to the elements of each of *those* lists.  How variable is your nested list structure?

Comment: `a = [list(map(float, x)) for x in a]`

Comment: Remember that maps and list comprehensions are very similar processes. Try both and see which you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

For nested data, use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension):

```
>>> a = [['1312.98680732', 14.28625384], ['1312.98680735', 20.303], ['1312.98680736', 9.78438636]]
>>> [[float(x) for x in group] for group in a]
[[1312.98680732, 14.28625384], [1312.98680735, 20.303], [1312.98680736, 9.78438636]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to go through the old list and generate a new one. Use list unpacking to separate the list of two values at each outer list location.

```
a = [[float(s), v] for s,v in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(map(lambda l: list(map(float, l)), a))
```

if you do not want to use list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first element of your secondary list which is a string, then you could iterate through your first list (`a`) and for each list inside `a`, convert the first item to `float`, like this:

```
for item in a:
    item[0] = float(item[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a list of lists. You want to cast the first item in those inner lists to a float. You can do this with list comprehension.

```
[[float(item[0]), item[1]] for item in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
a = [[float(n) for n in b] for b in value["a"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using `isinstance()`:

```
a = [[float(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst] for lst in a]
```

Which gives:

```
[[1312.98680732, 14.28625384], [1312.98680735, 20.303], [1312.98680736, 9.78438636]]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
a = [['1312.98680732', 14.28625384],
     ['1312.98680735', 20.303],
     ['1312.98680736', 9.78438636]]


print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:float(y),x)),a)))
```

output:

```
[[1312.98680732, 14.28625384], [1312.98680735, 20.303], [1312.98680736, 9.78438636]]
```